# connection string for a vb.net application to be deployed in random system

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I am facing problem in using vb.net with sql server as DB..
Problem is of connection string i.e
for 'n' no. Of systems what shall be the connection string?
App after geting deployed in other system  creates connection path error.
what shall be coded so that connection string is defined automatically .?
please share any link or explanation for the same

Comment: Put it in configuration and have your installer switch it out.

Comment: Sorry but i am stiil not clear ...

Comment: Can u share any code with demo of app.config and form.vb's new sqlconnection object's path of datasource

Answer (score 1):

Below is a VB.Net code snippet to retrieve a connection string from the app.config.  The project will need a reference to System.Configuration in order to use the ConfigurationManager.

```
Dim connectionString As String=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myDatabase").ConnectionString
```

An example App.Config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Datasource=my server... Wat does dat mean?? Sory for stupid question but if i m installing my app in new system won't the server name change?? Pardon again...... I would have upvoted u but u can see the reputation points...: ( sorry

Comment: One of fhe other big problem is when i tried dis...inly select query runs! The insert query doesnt!

Comment: The value after the Data Source keyword is the host name of the SQL Server.  In the case of a named instance, append backslash and the instance name (e.g. MyServer\SQLEXPRESS).

Comment: Regarding your problem with the insert statement, I suggest you post a new question and include the code since it's not related to the initial connection.